# Compare two large dictionaries and create lists of values for keys they have in common

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a two dictionaries like:

```
dict1 = { (1,2) : 2, (2,3): 3, (1,3): 3}
dict2 = { (1,2) : 1, (1,3): 2}
```

What I want as output is two list of values for the items which exist in both dictionaries:

```
[2,3]
[1,2]
```

What I am doing right now is something like this:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

for key in dict1.keys():
    if key in dict2.keys():
        list1.append(dict1.get(key))
        list2.append(dict2.get(key))
```

This code is taking too long running which is not something that I am looking forward to. I was wondering if there might be a more efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
commons = set(dict1).intersection(set(dict2))
list1 = [dict1[k] for k in commons]
list2 = [dict2[k] for k in commons]
```

Comment: I was just about to answer with something like this. Beat me to it! :)

Comment: Beat me by a sec. But you don't need the keys call or the second set call.

Comment: @BlackBear -- You can actually get the intersection without constructing additional sets.  `common = dict1.viewkeys() & dict2` on python2.x, or `common - dict1.keys() & dict2` on python3.x

Comment: @BlackBear Thanks, worked like a charm. You might want to rename "common" to "commons" or the other way around.

Comment: @mgilson thank you too for the tip :) (I won't edit since everything is already in your answer)

Answer (score 14):

Don't use `dict.keys`.  On python2.x, it creates a new list every time it is called (which is an `O(N)` operation -- And `list.__contains__` is another `O(N)` operation on average).  Just rely on the fact that dictionaries are iterable containers directly (with `O(1)` lookup):

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

for key in dict1:
    if key in dict2:
        list1.append(dict1.get(key))
        list2.append(dict2.get(key))
```

---

Note that on python2.7, you can use `viewkeys` to get the intersection directly:

```
>>> a = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'qux'}
>>> b = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> a.viewkeys() & b
set(['foo'])
```

(on python3.x, you *can* use `keys` here instead of `viewkeys`)

```
for key in dict1.viewkeys() & dict2:
    list1.append(dict1[key]))
    list2.append(dict2[key]))
```

Comment: I really prefer this method as it avoids using extra data structure and makes good use of dict's object methods.

Comment: Very useful if comparing more than two dictionaries. Thanks

Comment: Why is there even a need to use `.keys()` and why using it with only one dictionary is enough?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost -- in my opinion, on python2.x, there is almost never a good reason to use `.keys()`.  If you want a list of a dictionary's keys, then you use `list(d)` since that works on python3.x as well.  If you want to iterate over a dictionary's keys, you just do `for key in d: ...`.  On python3.x, `d.keys` does the same thing as `d.viewkeys` for python2.7.  That method _is_ useful since it is more efficient and behaves like a `set` in a lot of ways.  (See my example above for computing common keys between 2 dictionaries).

Comment: @mgilson I was asking why you call `viewkeys()/keys()` on `dict1` but not on `dict2`? Also shouldn't `&` operator work for every container automatically which would make it possible to call just `dict1 & dict2`?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost `dict1 & dict2` doesn't work.  `dict1.viewkeys() & dict2` works because of the implementation of a dict "`keys_view`" object returned by `.viewkeys()`.  `dict1.viewkeys() & dict2.viewkeys()` would work too -- IIRC, a `keys_view` instance can be `&`ed with any iterable just fine.  I've always felt like this was was a little flaky because `keys_view` are obviously modeled after `set` -- and `set` can only `&` with another `set` (though they do have the `.intersection` method which works with any iterable...)  I'd actually like to see the `keys_view` object behave more set-like.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension within `zip()` function:

```
>>> vals1, vals2 = zip(*[(dict1[k], v) for k, v in dict2.items() if k in dict1])
>>> 
>>> vals1
(2, 3)
>>> vals2
(1, 2)
```

Or as a more functional approach using view object and `operator.itemgetter()` you can do:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> intersect = dict1.viewkeys() & dict2.viewkeys()
>>> itemgetter(*intersect)(dict1)
(2, 3)
>>> itemgetter(*intersect)(dict2)
(1, 2)
```

Benchmark with accepted answer:

```
from timeit import timeit


inp1 = """
commons = set(dict1).intersection(set(dict2))
list1 = [dict1[k] for k in commons]
list2 = [dict2[k] for k in commons]
   """

inp2 = """
zip(*[(dict1[k], v) for k, v in dict2.items() if k in dict1])
   """
inp3 = """
intersect = dict1.viewkeys() & dict2.viewkeys()
itemgetter(*intersect)(dict1)
itemgetter(*intersect)(dict2)
"""
dict1 = {(1, 2): 2, (2, 3): 3, (1, 3): 3}
dict2 = {(1, 2): 1, (1, 3): 2}
print 'inp1 ->', timeit(stmt=inp1,
                        number=1000000,
                        setup="dict1 = {}; dict2 = {}".format(dict1, dict2))
print 'inp2 ->', timeit(stmt=inp2,
                        number=1000000,
                        setup="dict1 = {}; dict2 = {}".format(dict1, dict2))
print 'inp3 ->', timeit(stmt=inp3,
                        number=1000000,
                        setup="dict1 = {}; dict2 = {};from operator import itemgetter".format(dict1, dict2))
```

Output:

```
inp1 -> 0.000132083892822
inp2 -> 0.000128984451294
inp3 -> 0.000160932540894
```

For dictionaries with length 10000 and random generated items, in 100 loop with:

```
inp1 -> 1.18336105347
inp2 -> 1.00519990921
inp3 -> 1.52266311646
```

## Edit:

As @Davidmh mentioned in comment for refusing of raising an exception for second approach you can wrap the code in a `try-except` expression:

```
try:
    intersect = dict1.viewkeys() & dict2.viewkeys()
    vals1 = itemgetter(*intersect)(dict1)
    vals2 = itemgetter(*intersect)(dict2)
except TypeError:
    vals1 = vals2 = []
```

Comment: I think that the readability of the accepted answer outweighs an ~10% timing difference ;-)

Comment: You are never testing the third option, only the second one twice. Plus, the third option crashes if there are no common keys.

Comment: @Davidmh Yes, I just update the answer. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with `keys` in python3 and `viewkeys` in python2. These are view objects that behave like sets, and cost no extra effort to construct them... they are just "views" of the underlying dictionary keys. This way you save the construction of `set` objects.

```
common = dict1.viewkeys() & dict2.viewkeys()
list1 = [dict1[k] for k in common]
list2 = [dict2[k] for k in common]
```

`dict_views` objects can be intersected directly with dictionaries, thus the following code works as well. I would prefer the previous sample though.

```
common = dict1.viewkeys() & dict2
```